# Question about line of curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

> If $\alpha$ is a planar geodesic on surface $M$, show that $\alpha$ is a line of curvature.

My try:

$\alpha$ planar imply torsion=0, and binomial vector is constant. Since $0=\kappa_g=\kappa_\alpha B\cdot U$, ($U$ is normal vector of $M$), so B perpendicular to $U$.  Here's where I stuck. Please help

Comment: Re. your user page:  I too am deeply impressed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, suppose $\textbf{$\alpha$}$ is arc-length parametrized.  Since $\textbf{$\alpha$}$ is a geodesic, we know its normal vector $\textbf{N}$ is collinear with the surface normal $\textbf{n}$.  That is, $\textbf{N} = \pm \textbf{n}$.

From this, we have $S_p(\textbf{T}) = -D_{T}\textbf{n} = \pm D_T\textbf{N}= \pm \frac{d\textbf{N}}{ds} = \pm (-\kappa \textbf{T} + \tau \textbf{B})$

Can you finish up and conclude that $\textbf{T}$ is an eigenvector of the shape operator at all points along $\textbf{$\alpha$}$?

---

Unfortunately, differential geometry notation differs widely from text to text, so I will take a moment to clarify the above:

- $\textbf{$\alpha$}$ is our given curve.
- $\textbf{T}$, $\textbf{N}$, and $\textbf{B}$ are the three vectors in the Frenet frame of $\textbf{$\alpha$}$.  They represent the unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors to $\textbf{$\alpha$}$.
- $\textbf{n}$ is the unit normal to $T_pM$ at a given point.  I.e. it is the 'surface normal'.
- $S_p$ denotes the shape operator of $M$.
- $D_\mathbf{v}X$ denotes the directional derivative of $X$ in the direction $\textbf{v}$.

Comment: Actually which part of your prof used $\tau=0$?

Comment: That's in the part I've left to you.  :)  To finish up, ask yourself what it means for a vector ($\textbf{T}$) to be an *eigenvector* of a matrix.

Comment: Ah ha, I used this fact without noticing..

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\alpha(s)$ is parametrized by its arc-length $s$; set, in the usual Frenet-Serret notation, $T(s) = \alpha'(s)$, so that $T(s)$ is the unit tangent vector to $\alpha(s)$.  It is indeed true that, since $\alpha(s)$ is a planar curve, we must have the torsion of $\alpha(s)$, $\tau(s) = 0$ *as long as the curvature $\kappa(s)$ of $\alpha(s)$ is non-zero*, $\kappa(s) \ne 0$.  This follows from the fact that $\alpha(s)$ lies in some plane $P$; thus $T(s)$ must also be tangent to $P$ for all $s$; hence $N(s) = (\kappa(s))^{-1} T'(s)$ must be tangent to $P$ as well.  These assertions may be readily verified by expressing $\alpha(s)$ in the form $\alpha(s) = \beta + \alpha_1(s) \vec e_1 + \alpha_2(s) \vec e_2$, where the $\vec e_i$, $i = 1, 2$ are *constant* orthonormal vectors which span $P$ and $\beta$ itself is a constant vector; thus $T(s) = \alpha'(s) = \alpha_1'(s) \vec e_1 + \alpha_2'(s) \vec e_2$ and $N(s) = (\kappa(s))^{-1}T'(s) = (\kappa(s))^{-1}(\alpha_1''(s) \vec e_1 + \alpha_2''(s) \vec e_2)$ are both tangent to $P$.  We have in turn that $B(s) = T(s) \times N(s)$ is a continuous unit vector field along $\alpha(s)$ which is normal to $P$; thus it must be constant whence $0 = B'(s) = -\tau(s) N(s)$ forces $\tau = 0$.  Since $\tau(s) = 0$, the Frenet-Serret equations give $N'(s) = - \kappa(s) T(s)$.  Now the fact that $\alpha(s)$ is geodesic in $M$ implies that the component of its normal vector tangent to $M$ vanishes, which in turn allows us to conclude the $N(s)$ is in fact a surface normal vector field to $M$ along $\alpha(s)$.  But, denoting the shape operator of $M$ by $S$, we have

$S(T(s)) = \nabla_{T(s)}N(s) = \dfrac{N(s)}{ds} = \kappa(s) T(s), \tag{1}$

that is, $T(s)$ is an eigenvector of $S$ with eigenvalue $\kappa(s)$.  We thus see that $\alpha(s)$ is a line of curvature of the surface $M$.  ***QED.***

***PLEASE NOTE*** once again that I have added the assumption $\kappa(s) \ne 0$; this is tantamount to the hypothesis that $N(s) = (\kappa(s))^{-1} T'(s)$ is *defined* along $\alpha(s)$; I don't at present know how to be rid of this assumption, and would be interested in seeing a generalization of this result which lifts the restriction $\kappa(s) \ne 0$.  Furthemore, I take $S(T(s)) = \nabla_{T(s)}N(s)$ whereas Kaj takes $S$ to be of opposite sign.  But the result is the same in any event.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***